# OPP nomenclature question: object->function($param)

Tags: php, oop, object, nomenclature

In OOP, what do call it when you do:

```
$o = new ClassInstance();

$o->someFunction($p);
```

For example, I would say I'm passing the parameter p to the function someFunction.  Easy.

**But how do you articulate** the calling of a function in the class object, ClassInstance?  You're not really passing the function someFunction to the object ClassInstance.... so would you say: "Call the someFunction function in the ClassInstance object?"

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Call method `someFunction` from object `$o` (which is an instance of class `ClassInstance`), passing `$p` as an argument.".

Rephrasing for clarity:

```
$instance = new ClassName();
$instance->someMethod($p);
```

"Call method `someMethod` from object `$instance` (which is an instance of class `ClassName`), passing `$p` as a parameter (or argument)".